# GTK+ C compilation errors Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, user-interface, visual-studio-2012, gtk

I am trying to compile a simple GTK+ C program in VS2012. After getting GTK+ to work in VS2012, I decided to try a simple program to see if it would compile and run correctly. I'm getting a few compilation errors that I'm sure can be solved I just don't know how to solve them. Here is my source:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) 
{ 
    gtk_main_quit(); 
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv); 
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL); 
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Window"); 
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL); 
    gtk_widget_show_all(window); 
    gtk_main(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

These are the errors I am getting:

```
+-------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+---+------------------+
| Error | 1 | error C2275: 'GtkWidget' : illegal use of this type as an expression | c:\users\pr0d1gy\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\cassemblyexample\cassemblyexample\source.c | 10 | 1 | CAssemblyExample |
| Error | 2 | error C2065: 'window' : undeclared identifier                        | c:\users\pr0d1gy\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\cassemblyexample\cassemblyexample\source.c | 10 | 1 | CAssemblyExample |
| Error | 3 | error C2065: 'window' : undeclared identifier                        | c:\users\pr0d1gy\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\cassemblyexample\cassemblyexample\source.c | 11 | 1 | CAssemblyExample |
| Error | 4 | error C2065: 'window' : undeclared identifier                        | c:\users\pr0d1gy\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\cassemblyexample\cassemblyexample\source.c | 12 | 1 | CAssemblyExample |
| Error | 6 | error C2065: 'window' : undeclared identifier                        | c:\users\pr0d1gy\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\cassemblyexample\cassemblyexample\source.c | 13 | 1 | CAssemblyExample |
+-------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+---+------------------+
```

Comment: You have included `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`. Can you confirm that this folder and file is available under standard system folder of your VS2012 installation?

Comment: So in my VC++ Directories for the project I have added paths to GTK includes, GTK libraries, and GTK source.

Comment: In that case, can you try to modify your include `#include "gtk/gtk.h"` and check?

Comment: That didn't work. I'm getting the same errors.

Comment: Are you using a `C++` compiler or `C` compiler? If you are using a `C` compiler, `GtkWidget *window` will have to be declared before `gtk_init(&argc, &argv);` is invoked.

Comment: That solved it but I now have 10 LNK errors:

Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_type_check_instance_cast referenced in function _main
Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_signal_connect_data referenced in function _main
etc....

Comment: For the linker errors, you will have check the dependent libraries and their paths in your `VS2012` environment. Please check if all the dependent libraries are in `Project Settings --> Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies`.

Comment: Ok thank you for your time. You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using a `C` compilation mode, your variables should be declared before the first executable statement of your function. Hence, in your code snippet above, `GtkWidget *window` should be declared before the first executable statement of your code i.e. `gtk_init(&argc, &argv);`

Comment: AFAIK, you may declare variables where you want in C99. It's just that [Visual Studio is years behind other compilers for C99 support](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/05/vs_c99_support/).

Comment: Still same problem after doing your advise, i do not see the GUI at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384773/how-to-make-gtk-work-on-visual-studio-2010